# syntax error on if["$foo" == "bar"] in bash

Tags: bash

I am new to bash, but according to some flow control guides I saw, this script should work just find, but I get `line 4 syntax error near unexpected token then`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Type your name"
read personname
if["$personname" == "kevin"]; then
    echo "Your name is kevin"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the shell, `[` is a command and `]` is an argument to that command. Arguments must be separate words, separated by white space. Aside from that, I would also suggest changing your `==` to `=` (the latter is more widely supported). Also, you can combine your `echo` and `read` statements using `read -p`.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p $'Type your name\n' personname
if [ "$personname" = "kevin" ]; then
    echo "Your name is kevin"
    exit 1
fi
```

The `$'string\n'` syntax allows you to use characters such as the newline `\n` in the prompt string. If you don't actually want a newline, you could simply use something like `'Type your name: '` and the prompt would appear on the same line as the user input.

Comment: Might make wording a bit more exact -- a command, yes; a function, no.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing some spaces in if statement

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Type your name"
read personname
if [ "$personname" == "kevin" ]; then
    echo "Your name is kevin"
    exit 1
fi
```